How do I chase down this old PubMed article?
I found this interesting article and would like to read it: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3551058/. I have a title and author and PubMed ID, but no DOI and not much else to go off. Also the author died in 1997.
How can I hunt down and read this article?

Dear OP, please see our canonical question for such requests.

What do you mean by "not much else to go off"? The full citation is on the PubMed page you link... You'll probably just have to ask your library if they can help obtain papers from Schweizerische Medizinische Wochenschrift.
